# OpenGL constant rotation angle

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rotation, glut

I am doing some openGL programming lately and it invovles basic matrix transformation such as translation, rotation and scaling. I encounter some problems when doing rotation. Here is my question.

Now I am using a variable rotationDegree and a variable rotationStepSize to control the rotation. When the rotation flag is on

```
//inside paintGL function
if(rotationFlag is on)
     rotationDegree += rotationStepSize
     if(rotationDegree > 360.0f)
         rotationDegree -= 360.0f
```

Here's the strange thing, Since I define rotationStepSize to be very small, the rotation starts out very slow, but then as time increases it gets faster and faster!

I come up with two explanations for this phenomena:

- 360f is not the range of values for the degree parameter in glm::rotate
- The program starts out slow, causing paintGL to be painted to screen less. Then as the program become steady(or other parameter is not changing), the mainLoopEvent is executing faster and faster, causing paintGL to be painted more.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I googled about using glutget(GL_TIME_ELAPSED), but on my machine, this function reports "glutget: missing ENUM handle", which indicates that my glut file is not complete, I guess?

So does anyone know how to fix the enum problem or how to get around this to create a scene where I have an object rotating in constant speed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: just a bet but have you use `glLoadIdentity`  or any other matrix reset method ? if not then you are rotating already rotated matrix meaning that the step increment is speed instead.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in the question details. I am using new openGL, featuing programmable pipeline. Each time I will translate the object back to the origin, rotate by the degree specified in rotationDegree and translate the  object back to its original position. All these are put inside one matrix and then I will pass this modelToWorld matrix to the vertex shader.

Comment: the point stays check if the matrix is unit (or in defined initial state) before each frame ...

Comment: @Spektre yes, but I did make sure of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**freeglut_state.c**](http://fooo.fr/~vjeux/climb/olena-2.0/external/trimesh/gluit/freeglut_state.c), there is the glutGet function defined.

```
int FGAPIENTRY glutGet( GLenum eWhat )
{
#if TARGET_HOST_WIN32 || TARGET_HOST_WINCE
    int returnValue ;
    GLboolean boolValue ;
#endif

    switch (eWhat)
    {
        case GLUT_INIT_STATE:
        return fgState.Initialised;

        case GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME:
        return fgElapsedTime();
    }
```

I'm not using freeglut, but look at the docmentation, maybe you should try `GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME` instead of `GL_TIME_ELAPSED`?

And calculate the deltatime like this:

```
int preTime= 0;
while( ... )
{
     int currentTime= glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
     int deltaTime = currentTime- preTime;
     preTime = currentTime;

     //... pass the deltaTime to whatever you want...
}
```